# GUI broken or renders improperly - Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, graphics, configuration, gui

Simply, the GUI windows are breaking down.

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the text in the launched windows is unreadable.There's also some black shade around the corners of the active window. 
I don't know why this occurs, and most of the time it happens to every window (Not only for the window in the screenshot).

Here's my system configuration

```
Memory : 2.9 GiB
Processor : Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz × 2 
Graphics : Intel® G33 x86/MMX/SSE2
OS Type: 32-bit
Disk : 75.5 GB
```

> Linux John 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24
>   21:18:00 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

So here are my questions:

1) Is this happening,because of the low system configuration? If yes, which would be the most suitable linux distribution for the above configuration ?  (I just want to run Android Studio in the OS).

2) If it's not a system configuration problem, How can I fix this?

If you have any questions, ask me in the comments please.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run a lighter desktop even if you can fix the glitching.  Mate is pretty good for low-spec setups.  You don't need another distro, just add mate to your existing setup.  They have some fairly good documentation on getting setup.

http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: Could  you please explain the above commands. ?

Comment: @AxeFox. it resets the Unity desktop

Comment: I'm not at home, i'll tell you once it worked.